# RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo ... ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.*.chat/com.*.login.LoginActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.*.login.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.*.chat-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.*.chat-1/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

I have tried everything I could find online without success.  The only way I could get around this by this inefficient script I made:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./gradlew app:clean
./gradlew app:installDebug
./gradlew app:clean
./gradlew app:installDebug

/home/adel/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n com.*.chat/com.*.login.LoginActivity

notify-send -i icon.png "gradle task done" "check your phone"
```

It works, but takes around 7 minutes to get done.  Is there a faster, more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: why are you invoking same things twice? why the wildcards?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I'm not sure why but if I build once I get "ClassNotFoundException" exception, I found out invoking same things twice fix this problem ... wild card because I don't want people googling app name to find this question

Comment: So, fix the ClassNotFoundException problem first. And how are people looking at this question to give you an answer supposed to guess that you are hiding the package with wildcard?

Comment: Yeah if you notice the question is about ClassNotFoundException problem I need to fix, building the project twice without any modifications makes the problem vanish, go figure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just this:

`./gradlew --offline clean assembleDebug`

To send .apk to your device use something like that:

`adb install app/build/output/apk/appDebug.apk`

Ensure your apk filename and the path are correct.

Comment: hi @mklimek ... thank for help, I have to use line  `./gradlew --offline clean assembleDebug` twice to escape error but that did reduce build time to 4 minutes, thank you

Comment: I think I will accept your answer, it didn't fix the original problem but it made the workaround less painful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have stopped the Instant run from Android studio and its working.

File->Setting->Build->Instant Run->Disble checkbox of Enable instant run to hotswap code/resource changes